# One or optionally more functions as function params

Tags: javascript

In reference to Express app.post function shown below, I am trying to find documentation behind using one or optionally more than one callback function as parameters in the app.post function

I've researched the web, understood the concept behind spread operator, understand it means 2nd callback function or more but can't find any tutorial / reference on brackets [  ] as syntax for 'optionally' more than one

app.post(path, callback [, callback ...])

What I hope to understand or find a clear reference / tutorial on are:

1. Reference explaining the [  ] syntax
2. What is the sequence of execution to the callbacks passes, so assuming I called it as app.post(....., callback1, callback2);
   will callback1, callback2 be called in the same time? or will callback2 be called once callback1 returns?
3. Will the result returned from callback1 passed to callback2 as parameters (despite the parameters of callback2)?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: not sure about 2 and 3 but [] probably means array

Comment: No, @chris, optional as the OP said.

Answer (score 1):

1) Thats an optional parameter. You can either call it as if the parameters in the brackets would be there or as if the parameters in the brackets would not exist. So

```
 method(a, [b, c])
 // Could be either called as
 method(a)
 // or as
 method(a, b, c)
```

2) `callback2` gets executed when you call `next` (the third argument) from `callback1`, `callback3` gets executed when you call `next` from `callback2` and so on.

3) No, all middlewares receive the request as their first, the reponse as their second and a next function as their third argument.

---

The usecase of these additional callbacks is to add middlewares to certain endpoints only:

```
  function isAdmin(req, res, next) {
    if(/*some checks*/) {
      next(); // Go to next middleware
    } else {
      res.status(402).send("Not authenticated!");
    }
 }

  app.post("/secret", isAdmin, function(req, res, next) {
    //...
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, so by point 3 this means upon calling next in Callback1, Callback2 will receive the result of calling Callback1 as Callback2 res parameter, correct?

In other words assuming those are not calbacks but rather regular functions app.post(path, function1 [, function2 ...]) now assuming function1 will return an array will this array be passed automatically as param of function2?